# What does this code mean

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I found a code segment. I do not understand it. It seems that the variable __rem is useless at all. The line below does not do any useful work yet:

```
(void)(((typeof((n)) *)0) == ((uint64_t *)0));   \
```

The whole code segment is as below:

```
#define do_div(n,base)  do{             \
    uint32_t __base = (base);           \
    uint32_t __rem;                 \
    (void)(((typeof((n)) *)0) == ((uint64_t *)0));   \
    if (((n) >> 32) == 0) {         \
        __rem = (uint32_t)(n) % __base;     \
        (n) = (uint32_t)(n) / __base;       \
    } else                      \
        __rem = __div64_32(&(n), __base);   \
    __rem;                      \
 }while(0)
/* Wrapper for do_div(). Doesn't modify dividend and returns
 * the result, not reminder.
 */
static inline uint64_t lldiv(uint64_t dividend, uint32_t divisor)
{
    uint64_t __res = dividend;
    do_div(__res, divisor);
    return(__res);
}
```

Why is the useless code here?

Comment: compiler sanity check?

Comment: Again, please provide information about the toolchain. This is obviously a compiler intrinsic (double-undersores in identifiers).

Comment: It is from the file div64.h in uboot. I copy it and it works well at first. But when I compiled it with RVDS 5.01. The compiler complained with "expression has no effect". @Quentin

Comment: @user1651758 Why do you copy internals from one library into a program compiled with another ? Besides, this sounds like a compiler bug, as the expression's result is explicitly discarded.

Comment: Double underscores are actually forbidden for any use, see the standard 7.1.3. The compiler is not allowed to use them for its own tricks, nor is the programmer. They are reserved for future C standard additions.

Comment: `__rem` is useless , perhaps the author of this code copy-pasted it in from elsewhere and decided to not much with it. In general you might want to know `rem` after doing this algorithm. As a wild guess, perhaps this code used to be in a gcc *statement-expression*, where the `__rem;` at the end means that the final value of `__rem` is the "return value" of the statement-expression

Comment: @Lundin are you 100% sure ? GCC's standard library code is riddled with them...

Comment: @Quentin I'm not sure at all. Historically, there's been plenty of confusion where the standard says that certain identifiers are "reserved", but not reserved for who. Compiler manufacturers have decided to interpret it as "reserved for the compiler", while the intention might actually have been "reserved for future extensions of the C language". It was clarified somewhat in C99, but by then no compiler is going to rewrite all of their internal libs. This is all pretty muddy.

Comment: @Lundin The existence of `_Bool` and `_Alignas` would hint at the second one, but it's unclear indeed. Fortunately, from a user's perspective, the answer is just *"doooooooon't"*.

Comment: @sergej Yes. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## 1. `(void)(((typeof((n)) *)0) == ((uint64_t *)0));`

See `Linux/include/asm-generic/div64.h`:

> The unnecessary pointer compare is there
>   to check for type safety (n must be 64bit)

**Example:**

`n` must be `int`, but it is `short`

```
void main()
{
    short n;
    (void)(((typeof((n)) *)0) == ((int *)0));
}
```

We get the warning:
**`comparison of distinct pointer types lacks cast`**

Compiled with: `gcc -o main main.c`

Compiler version: `gcc (GCC) 4.9.2 20141101 (Red Hat 4.9.2-1)`

**Conclusion:**

The pointer compare is not useless. It generates a warning if the variable passed to `do_div()` has a wrong type.

## 2. __rem

The code surrounded by braces is a gcc statement-expressions.
`__rem` is, so to say, the return value of `do_div()`.

**Example:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define do_div(n,base)  ({ \
    int __rem = n % base;  \
    n /= base;             \
    __rem;                 \
})

int main()
{
    int a = 9;
    int b = 2;
    int c = 0;

    printf("%i / %i = ", a, b);
    c = do_div(a, b);
    printf("%i, reminder = %i\n", a, c);
    return 0;
}
```

Output: `9 / 2 = 4, reminder = 1`

In the example above, `c = do_div(a, b)` is equivalent to `c = ({int rem = a % b; a /= b; rem;})`.

**Conclusion:**

`__rem` is not useless it is the "return value" of `do_div()`.

Comment: Weird that this produces a warning by default, it's perfectly legitimate: `C11 draft standard: 6.3.2.3 Pointers 4 [...]Any two null pointers shall compare equal.[...]`.

Comment: Oh, it produces a warning on my gcc 4.8.4 as well. I was just surprised it doesn't require `-Wall` or `-Wextra` or something like that.

Comment: @EOF that is saying they shall compare equal *after* conversion to the same type.  However conversion to the same type requires a cast in this case. (C11 6.5.8/2)

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I assume you mean 6.5.9/2?

Comment: Hi! It's a very late question, but the original source doesn't seem to use the result value _rem of do_div(). What does the statement `__rem;  ` mean here?